How do I debug on Coder Codeserver
My company use Coder as a code server. I am stuck on how to debug my React (NextJS) code on it.
My launch.json file looks like this:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "urlFilter": "https://{port}.{my-name}.code-server.{my-company-domain}/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/{path-to-my-folder}"
    }
  ]
}

And I got this error thrown by JavaScript Debugger Extension:

We can't launch a browser in debug mode from here. Open this workspace in VS Code on your desktop to enable debugging.

How do I debug on this platform?
